# Passing a two dimensional array to a function

Tags: array, class, pointer

I'm working on an led matrix project where I'm running a series of patterns made of bitmap frames.

Here's an example: https://vimeo.com/564184465

Right now I'm using a series of method calls named per pattern to run the animation:

```
void CSMatrix::runPattern(PATTERNS pattern, uint8_t totalRuns)
{
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < totalRuns; i++)
  {
    switch (pattern)
    {
    case PATTERN_ZIG_ZAG:
      runPatternSpacedStripes();
      break;
    case PATTERN_ARROW_UP:
      runPatternArrowUp();
      break;
...
    }
  }
}

void CSMatrix::runPatternSpacedStripes()
{
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < SPACED_STRIPES_LEN; i++)
  {
    renderFrame(SPACED_STRIPES[i]);
    FastLED.show();
    delay(100);
  }
}

void CSMatrix::runPatternArrowUp()
{
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < ARROW_UP_LEN; i++)
  {
    renderFrame(ARROW_UP[i]);
    FastLED.show();
    delay(100);
  }
}

...
```

And the bitmaps used to control the matrix pixel states look like this (the functions beneath `renderFrame` basically say "if it's a 1, use this color, if it's a 0, use that color":

```
const byte SPACED_STRIPES[][8] = {
    {0b11000110,
     0b10001100,
     0b00011000,
     0b00110001,
     0b01100011,
     0b11000110,
     0b10001100,
     0b00011000},
    {0b01100011,
     0b11000110,
     0b10001100,
     0b00011000,
     0b00110001,
     0b01100011,
     0b11000110,
     0b10001100},
...    
};
const int SPACED_STRIPES_LEN = sizeof(SPACED_STRIPES) / 8;
```

This is working fine, but having a bunch of identical methods to run each pattern is not great.

So, with this working I decided to refactor to make a common `runTwoColorPattern` method that could accept the pattern frames and the length to run the given pattern:

```
void CSMatrix::runTwoColorPattern(const byte *frames, const int length, int delayDuration)
{
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    renderFrame(frames[i]);
    FastLED.show();
    delay(delayDuration);
  }
}
```

The problem I'm running into is figuring out how to properly pass the two dimensional array to the function.

I tried updating my switch statement by passing the pointer of `SPACED_STRIPES` into the `runTwoColorPattern`:

```
    switch (pattern)
    {
    case PATTERN_ZIG_ZAG:
      runTwoColorPattern(SPACED_STRIPES, SPACED_STRIPES_LEN, 100);
      //runPatternSpacedStripes();
      break;
```

But when I do I get the error

> argument of type "const byte (*)[8]" is incompatible with parameter of type "const byte *"C/C++(167)

[image: error]

I've found that I can correct this by dereferencing the first item of the multidimensional array, (which would mean I'm passing the memory address to the first pointer element of the multi-dimensional array (I think)), but when I do this the pattern runs backwards and is jittery :|

https://vimeo.com/564184624

I'm not totally sure how to correct this. I'm still fairly new to pointers so I'm sure there's something I'm misunderstanding with passing a pointer for a multi-dimensional array, but I thought what I was passing was basically an address of where to start for the pointer, so I'm not sure why I'm hitting these snags or how to fix it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You really don't need a 2D array for this - a simple 1D one will do and just use multiple-of-8 offsets to read each frame.

Comment: Aaaaaah that's true! I was running with this format b/c it was easy to visually parse and adjust the bitmaps by hand after generating them from an online calculator, but ultimately that format isn't needed. So to restate to make sure I understand: I can make a 1d array where each element is a single number representation of the frame and those numbers can be parsed 8 bits at a time to get the rows within the frame, right?

Comment: No, you'd just have a big "blob" of 8 bit values. Exactly as you have now, but without the `},{` between each frame. Then frame 0 starts at offset 0. Frame 1 at offset 8. Frame 2 at offset 16, etc. Basically `&frames[i * 8]`

Comment: ah, even simpler. I'll give it a try and when i have it working I'll post an answer. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 2D array would be passed as `const byte frames[][8]`. However you really don't need the complexity of a 2D array - you can do it with a 1D array.

Your array would look like:

```cpp
const byte SPACED_STRIPES[] = {
     0b11000110,
     0b10001100,
     0b00011000,
     0b00110001,
     0b01100011,
     0b11000110,
     0b10001100,
     0b00011000,

     0b01100011,
     0b11000110,
     0b10001100,
     0b00011000,
     0b00110001,
     0b01100011,
     0b11000110,
     0b10001100,
...    
};
```

And you reference frames within it as a multiple of 8 of the index.  Using your existing code it would look like:

```cpp
void CSMatrix::runTwoColorPattern(const byte *frames, const int length, int delayDuration)
{
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    renderFrame(&frames[i * 8]); // Take the address of the first value of the frame at a multiple of 8
    FastLED.show();
    delay(delayDuration);
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked! I updated my pattern and the method and now the animations are running as expected. Implementing the changes also helped me understand exactly what you were going for; the structure of the multi-dimensional array helped me visually, but isn't necessary for the parsing. The other added benefit of doing it this way is that now that it's a flat array I can send through arbitrary sized blobs for different sized matricies (16x16, 32x32 ...) and just parameterize the multiplier for grabbing the pointer index. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Re “`const byte *frames[8]`”: you mean `const byte (*frames)[8]`.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I have never seen that format before in my life. I actually meant `frames[][8]`. Is `(*frames)[8]` some newer C++ syntax that didn't exist when I was taught C at uni?

Comment: AFAIK, `(*frames)[8]` is ANSI C, maybe even K&R C.

Comment: Well, I have only ever come across brackets like that when working with function pointers.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I have been scouring the interwebs, and I have found exactly one example using that format, with no explanation of what it is or how it works. I found one that uses `(*name)[X][Y]`, which claims to be passing a pointer to a 2D array, and that I can completely understand. I think `(*name)[X]` is passing a 2D array as a pointer to a 1D array. Valid, but kind of a hack. Nowhere seems to use it, all examples either being `*name[]` or `**name`, or `name[][X]`

Comment: You will find a couple of examples, with explanation, if you search for “C pointer to array” on stackoverflow. It's not a hack, it's standard syntax, albeit confusing enough for most people to avoid it. [`name[][X]` is implicitly translated by the compiler into `(*name)[X]`](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html), but this translation is done only within function parameter declarations. See also [How do I declare a pointer to an array?](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ptrtoarray.html) and [How to pass a two-dimensional array](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html) in the C FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is quite explicit:

> argument of type "const byte (*)[8]" is incompatible with parameter
> of type "const byte *"

If you want to pass `SPACED_STRIPES` to the method, it is going to be
passed as `const byte (*)[8]`, i.e. pointer to arrays of 8 `byte`. You
can just set the parameter type accordingly:

```cpp
void CSMatrix::runTwoColorPattern(
    const byte (*frames)[8], const int length, int delayDuration)
{
    // body unchanged
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I ended up going with the suggestion to simplify the array, but this answer helps me understand the error I was getting. I didn't realize I could write the method signature with the parens around the pointer.